# OnKeyPress event on itemtpl in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, onkeypress

I am new to sencha.The onkeypress event of a text box not seems to be firing when it used in itemtpl.This is my code:

```
 itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl><table width="100%"><tr><td width="10%"><div class="Drop_Down" id="pat_dropId"><input  type="text" onkeypress="{[this.myFunction()]}" </div></td></tr></table><tpl>',
 {
   myFunction: function(itemKey)
{
console.log('myFunction');
 }
}
```

The console logs 'myFunction' when the list is loading.When a key is pressed the key press event is not firing.My expectation to trigger my function on pressing the key from keyboard.Please help..I have been looking for a solution long time.

Comment: It's not firing because `this` in `{[this.myFunction()]}` in its context refers to the global object and not to `itemTpl`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually I need to pass a store value from itemtpl to the function.For that i asked this question.When i wrote the function in the controller the value getting is undefined.
Here is the code

onkeypress='myFunction(values.itemkey)'

Comment: Go with the anser from kevhender and pass a argument to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Lorenz is right, `this` does not refer to the `itemTpl` when the text field is modified.  Change the handler to call a global function, perhaps something in a controller:

```
onkeypress="MyApp.app.getController(\'MyController\').myFunction()"
```

MyController.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    //other config here

    myFunction: function() {
         //do something here
    }
});
```

**Update** (based on your comments elsewhere):

To pass arguments, just use the normal notation for a store value in an `XTemplate`.  Also make sure to surround the argument with quotes, if it is not a number/boolean:

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl><table width="100%"><tr>',
        '<td width="10%">',
            '<div class="Drop_Down" id="pat_dropId">',
                '<input  type="text" onkeypress="MyApp.app.getController(\'MyController\').myFunction(\'{myStoreValue}\')">',
            '</div>',
        '</td>',
    '</tr></table><tpl>'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

change your Ext.XTemplate code like that:

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate("<tpl><table width='100%'><tr><td width='10%'><div             class='Drop_Down' id='pat_dropId'>
<input  type='text' onkeypress='myFunction(this)'</div> </td></tr></table><tpl>")
```

that Function define in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(that){
        //your code 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually I need to pass a store value from itemtpl to the function.For that i asked this question.When i wrote the function in the controller the value getting is undefined.
Here is the code

onkeypress='myFunction(values.itemkey)'

Answer (score 0):

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl><table width="100%"><tr><td width="10%"><div class="Drop_Down"><input  style="color:green;display:block;width:50px;text-align:center;" type="text" pattern="\d*" id="{ItemKey}" onkeyup="myapp.app.getController(\'myappController\').TextboxKeyUp(this)" onfocus="myapp.app.getController(\'myappController\').TextFocus(this)" ></div></td></tr></table><tpl>',
```